# php pdo fetch not working with functions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong in this small php snippet

config.php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sidemenu;";
$q = $conn->query($sql);
```

php in my html file

```
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
while($r = $q->fetch()){
    echo "
    <li>
       <a class='gn-icon ".mysql_real_escape_string($r[0])."'>".mysql_real_escape_string($r[1])."
       </a>
    </li>";
}
```

Now this snippet works and as expected generates the list items for me from the database.
But now when i try something like this

```
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
function mainMenu(){
while($r = $q->fetch()){
    echo "
    <li>
       <a class='gn-icon ".mysql_real_escape_string($r[0])."'>".mysql_real_escape_string($r[1])."
       </a>
    </li>";
}
}
mainMenu();
```

Now this for some reason doesnt work, now i do not know php very clearly, just learned some database integration so please if anyone can tell what did i copied wrongly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the scope of the `mainMenu()` function that variables outside are not available inside, you need to pass variables as parameters such as:

```
mainMenu($q);
```

Please see more about [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Also, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not required when outputting data.

Comment: Oh i added that as i had some special characters in my db values, which when came in the original document caused some trouble , and thank you for the answer, i did not think in that way at all, still confused with traditional global scopes :p